# Testing MVC controller using reactor with WebClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/platform")
public class PlatformController {

  @Autowired
  private PlatformRepository platformRepository;


  @GetMapping
  public Flux<Platform> findAll() {
    log.info("Calling findAll platforms");
    return platformRepository.findAll();
  }
}


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebFluxTest
public class PlatformControllerTest {

  @MockBean
  private PlatformRepository platformRepository;


  @Test
  public void findAll() throws Exception {
    WebTestClient client = WebTestClient.bindToController(new PlatformController()).build();
    client.get()
        .uri("/api/v1/platform")
        .exchange()
        .expectStatus().isOk();
  }

}
```

Above I have attached a simple POC of what i want to achieve. I am   unable to inject the mock into the controller for my tests and the tests fails. Is there any other way to do this or am i missing some fundamental concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things started to work after i added the controller class to the context configuration.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
    PlatformController.class,
    MongoTestConfig.class
})
@WebFluxTest(PlatformController.class)
```

I think it could be a bug, as the controller should be in the context after being included in the WebFluxTest annotation.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-webflux-tests):

> @WebFluxTest auto-configures the Spring WebFlux infrastructure and
>   limits scanned beans to @Controller, @ControllerAdvice,
>   @JsonComponent, Converter, GenericConverter, and WebFluxConfigurer.
>   **Regular @Component beans are not scanned** when the @WebFluxTest
>   annotation is used.

Could you try to add your controller class inside `WebFluxTest` annotation?

```
@WebFluxTest(PlatformController.class)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not help. I have tried another approach as well. I tried adding the @WebFluxTest(PlatformController.class) and tried to Autowire WebTestClient. In that case it does not even call the controller. It replies back with a 404. – Nandagopal Sekar 23 secs ago   edit